# generar excel en shiny

Tags: excel, shiny

He creado el siguiente programa en Shiny con el que pretendo que apretando un el botón de "Generar Excel" me pueda descargar el excel.

Pero al hacerlo me sale un error en el que me indica que no encuentra el archivo.

¿Alguien sabe qué puede estar mal?

```
library(shinyjs)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
   useShinyjs(),
   titlePanel("Informe de categoría 360. Ecuación de ventas"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h4("Parámetros"),
       textInput("area", "Area"),
       textInput("seccion", "Seccion"),
       textInput("categoria", "Categoria"),
       textInput("per_ant", "Periodo anterior", placeholder="Separadas por comas, Formato AAAAMM"),
       textInput("per_act", "Periodo actual", placeholder="Separadas por comas, Formato AAAAMM"),
      actionButton("ok", "Generar cuadro")
   ),
    mainPanel(
       downloadButton("informe","Guardar Excel"),
       tableOutput("ecuacion")
    )
  )
))

shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {
    shinyjs::hide("informe")
    observeEvent(input$ok,{

    id<-showNotification("Ejecutando ...",duration=NULL,closeButton = FALSE,type="message")
    nombreinforme<-paste0("Ecuacion_venta_cat", input$categoria, ".csv")


    ecuacion_ventas<-ventas(as.integer(input$area),as.integer(input$seccion),as.integer(input$categoria),input$per_ant,input$per_act)

    output$ecuacion<-renderTable({
      ecuacion_ventas
    },rownames = TRUE)

    removeNotification(id)
    shinyjs::show("informe")

    setwd(tempdir())
    output$informe<- downloadHandler(
       filename = nombreinforme, 
      content = function(file) {
       write.csv2(x = ecuacion_ventas, file = nombreinforme , row.names = TRUE) 
      })
    })
  })
```

Muchas gracias,

Naiara.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que la función `ventas()`  genera un objeto de clase `"data.frame"` el único error es usar `file = nombreinforme` en la función `write.csv2()`. Prueba usando:

```
output$informe<- downloadHandler(
   filename = nombreinforme, 
  content = function(file) {
   write.csv2(x = ecuacion_ventas, file, row.names = TRUE) 
  })
```